# Minimize sum of trace/nuclear distance

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I come up with the following problem during my project. Let $\lambda_i, \phi_i \in \mathbb{C}^d$ be normalized vectors and $\mathcal{U}$ the space of unitary operators. Denote $d_*$ the [trace distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_distance) (or distance induced by Schatten 1-norm) between two operators.
$$\min_{U \in \mathcal{U}} \sum_{i=1}^m d_*^2 (U\lambda_i \lambda_i^\dagger U^\dagger, \phi_i\phi_i^\dagger)$$

My attempt: Since two input operators are of rank one, the objective [equals](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13500/relation-between-trace-distance-and-inner-product-between-pure-states) to
$$\sum_{i=1}^m 1- |\lambda_i^\dagger U^\dagger \phi_i|^2$$
The problem becomes maximizing $$\sum_{i=1}^m |\lambda_i^\dagger U^\dagger \phi_i|^2 = \left\| \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^\dagger U^\dagger \phi_1 \\ ... \\ \lambda_m^\dagger U^\dagger \phi_m\end{bmatrix} \right\|^2_{F}.$$ Can I write the big norm compactly in terms of $\Lambda, \Phi$ (the matrices containing $\lambda_i$ and $\phi_i$ in their columns)? If possible, does it have a closed-form solution like [Procrustes problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276053/orthogonal-unitary-procrustes-problem-complex-matrices)? Otherwise, is there any other formulation (even modifying the initial optimization function is okay, as long as it captures the sum of distance between $U\lambda_i$ and $\phi_i$ and is invariant to the global phases of $\lambda_i$ and $\phi_i$, i.e. $d(\lambda,\phi) = d(e^{i\theta_1} \lambda, e^{i\theta_2} \phi)$.